# Print multiple IP Addresses from `ifconfig` in one line

Tags: linux

I would like to print out multiple IP Addresses from `ifconfig` in one line.

This is my attempt using `grep, cut and awk`

```
user@linux:~$ ifconfig | grep ad.*Bc
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet addr:10.1.1.1  Bcast:10.1.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
user@linux:~$ 

user@linux:~$ ifconfig | grep ad.*Bc | cut -d: -f2
192.168.1.1  Bcast
10.1.1.1  Bcast
user@linux:~$ 

user@linux:~$ ifconfig | grep ad.*Bc | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'
192.168.1.1
10.1.1.1
user@linux:~$
```

Unfortunately, the bst output I can get is

```
192.168.1.1
10.1.1.1
```

in 2 lines.

Is it possible to produce an output like this?

```
192.168.1.1 , 10.1.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try adding `|tr -s '\n' ','` in end

this replaces newline with comma.
Issue is there is no trailing endline which you can append later if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **Output Record Seperator** (`ORS`) as comma ( `,` ) in awk

```
ifconfig | grep ad.*Bc | cut -d: -f2 | awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" , ";} {print $1}' | sed 's#, $##' &&  echo ""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $(ifconfig | grep -o 'addr:[^ ]*' | cut -f2 -d:) | sed 's/ /, /g'
```

`grep -o` outputs only the string matching the pattern.
The `cut` command removes the `addr:` prefix (note that other linux versions e.g. Debian have a different `ifconfig` output that doesn't stick `addr:` to the address).

The result is joined into one line by making each "word" a parameter for echo by the `$( ... )` command substitution.

Finally `sed` replaces each space with `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another in a similar vein. This one handles both forms of `ifconfig` (yours produces lines starting `inet addr:10.11.12.13`, the other produces lines starting `inet 10.11.12.13`):

```
ifconfig | sed -nr 's/^.*?inet (addr:)?([0-9.]+).*/\2/p' | xargs | sed 's/ / , /g'
10.20.3.131 , 127.0.0.1
```

The same code also handles the result of `ip addr show` (also `ip a`) when you're ready to move on to `iproute2`:

```
ip a | sed -nr 's/^.*?inet (addr:)?([0-9.]+).*/\2/p' | xargs | sed 's/ / , /g'
127.0.0.1 , 10.20.3.131
```

In both cases you can omit the loopback addresses beginning with `127.` by inserting `grep -v '^127' into the pipeline before the`xargs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed

```
ifconfig | sed -n '
  $ {
  x
  s/^.//
  s/\n/ , /
  p
}
/.*addr:/!b
  s///
  s/ .*//
  H'
```

---

Keep all lines with 'addr:' in it
Remove all but keep IP in holdspace
At the end, get holdspace, format and print.